# Compare two columns highlight cells and display address of the cell

Tags: excel, vba, find, compare, highlight

I need to compare two columns with numbers. There may be several duplicates. I need to start find first value in C1 through B and highlight first coincidence with red and put address of that cell in D1
now i have only highlight first coincidence code

```
Sub Find_First()
Dim FindString As String
Dim myColor As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
myColor = Array("3")
On Error GoTo 0
FindString = Worksheets("2017").Range("C1").Value
    With TargetRange
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Rng.Interior.ColorIndex <> 3 Then
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = myColor(I)
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
        Else
        MsgBox "Colored"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hy

Sub Find()

    Dim WhatColumn As String, WhereColumn As String, ResultColumn As String
    
    WhatColumn = "A" 'main
    WhereColumn = "B" 'duplicates
    ResultColumn = "C" 'address of main
    
    'for speed
    Dim screenUpdate As Boolean, calc As Variant
    screenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    calc = Application.Calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    With ActiveSheet
        
        Dim i As Long, q As Long
        'trough te main
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, WhatColumn).End(xlUp).Row
            'sub loop 4 duplicates
            For q = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, WhereColumn).End(xlUp).Row
                If .Range(WhatColumn & i).Value = .Range(WhereColumn & q).Value Then
                    'we find ig
                    .Range(ResultColumn & q).Value = WhatColumn & i
                End If
            Next q
        Next i

    End With
    
    'restore default
    Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdate
    Application.Calculation = calc


End Sub
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks! but i need to find unique values. That is why i want to highlight first founded value and ignore in in next find process.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with `for`:

```
sub compare()

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

for i = 1 to LastRow
   if cells(i,3).value=cells(i,2).value then
        cells(i,2).interior.colorindex=3
        cells(i,3).interior.colorindex=3
        cells(i,4).value="B" & i
   end if
next i

end sub
```

Comment: it is working only when values are in same row. But have something like this: https://cloud.spkgroup.com/s/Po4HF8BFEjLS3rp